# How to get IP Address range from subnet and netmask

Tags: powershell

Team,

I am new to the forum, also new to the development, i am currently using windows 2016, 2012 & 2008 servers in the environment. The script primarily should work on all the environment.
I wanted to find out the IP start ip address and end ip address.

```
$params = @{
  "ComputerName" = "."
  "Class" = "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration"
  "Filter" = "IPEnabled=TRUE"
}
$netConfigs = Get-WMIObject @params
foreach ( $netConfig in $netConfigs ) {
  for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $netConfig.IPAddress.Count; $i++ ) {
    if ( $netConfig.IPAddress[$i] -match '(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}' ) {
  $ipString = $netConfig.IPAddress[$i]
  $ip = [IPAddress] $ipString
  $maskString = $netConfig.IPSubnet[$i]
  $mask = [IPAddress] $maskString
  $netID = [IPAddress] ($ip.Address -band $mask.Address)
  "IP address: {0}" -f $ip.IPAddressToString
  "Subnet mask: {0}" -f $mask.IPAddressToString
  "Network ID: {0}" -f $netID.IPAddressToString
    }
  }
}
```

Convert IP address to the subnet
[IPAddress] (([IPAddress] "192.168.100.45").Address -band ([IPAddress] "255.255.255.0").Address)

I am currently using 2016 & i am not getting how to proceed further to get the start ip address and end ip address in a single line of code.
Please advise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following to get the network and broadcast addresses:

```
$IP = '192.168.4.5'
$mask = '255.255.0.0'
$IPBits = [int[]]$IP.Split('.')
$MaskBits = [int[]]$Mask.Split('.')
$NetworkIDBits = 0..3 | Foreach-Object { $IPBits[$_] -band $MaskBits[$_] }
$BroadcastBits = 0..3 | Foreach-Object { $NetworkIDBits[$_] + ($MaskBits[$_] -bxor 255) }
$NetworkID = $NetworkIDBits -join '.'
$Broadcast = $BroadcastBits -join '.'

# Output
$NetworkID
192.168.0.0
$Broadcast
192.168.255.255
```

**Explanation:**

Since bitwise operators (see [About Arithmetic Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators?view=powershell-6)) are only supported on integer types, you must do a string to integer conversion to successfully use the operator<sup>[1]</sup>.

The IP and Mask are split on the `.` character creating a two string array of the octets. The `[int[]]` cast converts the array into an `Int32` array.

For the network address, we perform a `-band` (bitwise and) on the same index from each array. Since IPs have four octets, we only need to loop over the `0..3` range. The resulting `Int32` array (`$NetworkIDBits`) items joined by the `.` character, putting the result in IP address format.

For the broadcast address, we perform a `-bxor` (bitwise XOR) on the integer array derived from the mask with 255. The goal is to flip all of the ones and zeroes in the mask. The result will be an increment value per octet that can be added to the octets of the network address. The final, calculated result is converted to IP address form using `-join`.

---

<sup>[1]: You don't always need to explicitly cast strings to integers for the conversion. PowerShell can automatically do this in some cases. For example, in my shell, I do not have to cast with `[int[]]`</sup>

Comment: Thank you AdminofThings, final code. Added below lines to the code to get start and end of the network range.
$networkstart = $NetworkIDBits
$networkstart[3]= $networkstart[3]+1
$networkstart = $networkstart -join '.'
$networkend = $BroadcastBits
$networkend[3] = $networkend[3]-1
$networkend = $networkend -join'.'
$networkstart ; $networkend      Thank you for your direction, for me to get above details.

Answer (score 0):

The first ip is just the network address plus 1, although that is usually the gateway.  For the broadcast address, I'll just point to this link:  https://www.indented.co.uk/powershell-subnet-math/

> Getting to the Broadcast Address is a bit more complicated than the
>   Network Address. A Bitwise Or is executed against an Inverted Subnet
>   Mask. For example, the Inverted form of 255.255.255.0 is 0.0.0.255.